# Need a way to have front end wait for a lengthy process to finish without stopping system message flow

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I'm working with C# and .NET 4.0.

My program consists of a front-end and a back-end.  The back-end will be running as a Windows service that starts automatically at system start-up.  The front-end is a WPF application that the user will start when they're ready to work with the application.

As part of its start-up process, the front-end needs to establish communications with the back-end.  This is done using XMPP and works fine.  The code doing the communications has a BeginStart method that returns a WaitHandle.  Inside of a try-catch, I call BeginStart, get the WaitHandle, and call the Waithandle's WaitOne( TimeSpan ) method.  Note that the program is displaying a splash screen at this point.  And these calls are being made on the front-end thread.

While this is working fine, I've found that clicking on other windows while the WaitOne call is running has no effect.  Essentially, all Windows message traffic is halted waiting for this WaitHandle to return.

I believe I need to do the BeginStart and WaitOne call in another thread; I still need the front-end to wait for the WaitOne to return, as the program is supposed to die and no user interface is to display unless the WaitOne call returns successfully (no timeout).  It just needs to let other programs process their Windows messages.

How do I make this work?  There is no Application.DoEvents method in WPF.

Tony

Edit:

It looks like it may be helpful if I provide some more information.

My WPF application is the user interface for this product and only makes up half of the entire product.  The other half is running as a Windows service on the same PC and we call it the back-end.  What is going on in the back-end is unimportant, except that it is listening for connections to it using XMPP.

When the user interface (or front-end) starts up, one of the things it has to do is establish communications with the back-end using XMPP.  This should only take a second or two maximum normally.  However, there could be something wrong or the back-end could be down when the user starts the front-end.  I do not want the front-end to wait indefinitely; it needs to time out after a reasonable amount of time and display an error message and die.

To establish the communication, there's a module that runs as a separate thread that I start.  I am calling its BeginStart method, which returns a WaitHandle.  I then Wait on the WaitHandle, passing a TimeSpan set to my time out period.    Here's the snippet:

```
try {
    WaitHandle handle = BackgroundProcess.BeginStart();
    if ( !handle.WaitOne( Timeout ) ) {
        // Something went wrong; Notify user here
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure that the Background Process has started all of it's internal modules
    bool allAreRunning;
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Reset(); timer.Start();
    do {
        allAreRunning = true;
        foreach ( Module module in BackgroundProcess.Modules ) {
            if ( module.State != Module.States.Running ) {
                allAreRunning = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( !allAreRunning ) {
            // I hate this loop, but I can't think of a better way to do this
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        }

    } while ( !allAreRunning && timer.ElapsedMilliseconds <= Timeout.TotalMilliseconds );

    timer.Stop();

    if ( !allAreRunning ) {
        // Something went wrong; Notify user here
        return false;
    }

    // Other initialization done here

} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    // Something went wrong; Notify user here
    return false;
}
```

To test this, I have run the program in the debugger while the back-end was down.  I can click on any open window and switch to it and interact with it fine.  What I cannot do is click on the desktop. The WaitHandle.WaitOne() call returns very quickly, as that just returns once the background process has started running and does not wait for the connection to be established.  It's the do-while loop that's running for most of the time out period.

I need to rewrite this so the user can switch not just to open programs but click on the desktop, too.  I just don't know how to make it work.

Tony

Comment: One program should not be blocking all the other programs on the system.  Can you post the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way to code this start up logic.  The code, however, relies on the architecture of our internal code.

I was able to remove the do-while loop in the code snippet and replace it with better code.  Now, the code loops over all of the Module objects and queries them for their Running state WaitHandle.  These are added to a List collection.  After the loop completes, I convert the List into an array by calling .ToArray() and then call the WaitHandle.WaitAll method.

The code looks something like this now:

```
try {
    WaitHandle handle = BackgroundProcess.BeginStart();
    if ( !handle.WaitOne( Timeout ) ) {
        . . .
       return false;
    }

    List<WaitHandle> waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
    foreach ( Module module in BackgroundProcess.Transit.SubModules ) {
        WaitHandle waitHandle = module.GetWaitHandleForState( Module.States.Running );
        waitHandles.Add( waitHandle );
    }

    if ( !WaitHandle.WaitAll( waitHandles.ToArray(), Timeout ) ) {
        . . . 
        return false;
    }

    // If we get here, everything is communicating properly.
    . . .

} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    . . .
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 1):

You can move your call into a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and catch the WorkerCompleted event when your finished loading. You can also update the progress on the UI through the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: The process is running while the splash screen is being displayed.  There is nothing in the UI to update.  And I'm just waiting for a background process to establish a connection with a Windows service that's part of the application.  There's nothing to progress.  Please see my edit to my original question.

Comment: how are you waiting for the thread to return?  Can you post the code where your main thread is waiting for the child thread to finish?  There's a chance that your doing it in such a way that the main thread is still running.

Comment: I just noticed that your trying to do this in ASP.NET.  Don't thread in ASP.NET. you can make a web service call from your webpage, but it's not recommended to multi-thread your ASP.NET application.

Comment: This is not an ASP.NET application.  In the first paragraph of my question, I mention that the program I'm working on is a WPF application.

Comment: Sorry, your tags through me for a loop.